# InvalidCharacterError recaptcha__en.js

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I'm setting up recaptcha on my site, and when I view my page in IE11 I'm seeing an error and the checkbox doesn't display.

When I look at Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, and IE9 it works, but when I view IE11 and IE10 it throws an error.

I took my page from the example on: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : 'my_site_key'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the console I can see:

```
0: InvalidCharacterError  recaptcha__en.js (77, 9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reCAPTCHA requires that compatibility view is not enabled in order to work, see:

https://support.google.com/recaptcha/?hl=en-GB#6223838

Comment: Emulating IE11 through Edge turns on compatibility mode. Opening IE directly solved the issue.